# Почему я ловлю выход за пределы коллекции

Tags: java

Я хочу добавить в коллекцию 20 значений,почему при попытке вывести их на экран я ловлю ошибку?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rnd=new Random(1);
        List <Integer> array=new ArrayList();
        Iterator<Integer> iterator=array.iterator();
        for(int i=1;i<20;i++){
        array.add(rnd.nextInt(20)-10);
         System.out.println(array.get(i));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что элементы нумеруются с 0, а не с 1. Нужно изменить цикл, чтобы начинался с 0, а не с 1.